# two-factor authentication on GCE to prevent deletion

Tags: security, authentication, google-compute-engine

I wanted to know if there any way to protect my snapshots, disks, VMs, etc... on GCE so they can only be deleted with two-factor authentication, SMS or some token-based-app on smartphones, and how?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is something not yet available with Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 1):

While use of IAM roles as another poster suggested can limit the number of users who have role permissions to perform destructive operations, it is an authorization system, not a second factor authentication system. So, what you're asking exactly (a two-factor **auth** system) is not possible today on GCE.

As I represent the Product Management team for GCE, I am curious whether your aim is truly authentication/security, or if you are looking for a "safety check" to prevent accidental deletion by errant wildcard-type commands ("delete *"). The second feature is a request we have seen before and could be implemented by setting something like a "enable deletion of this resource" command that must be called first (and that in turn could be protected by IAM to a role that users don't normally have). Again, this is not something we have today, but it is being considered.

Answer (score -1):

I think protecting snapshots should be possible with new IAM roles feature. Check out the Compute Engine Storage section (roles/compute.storageAdmin) on this page:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

Comment: You think or you know? The document you reference in the link says that you can only allow/disallow access to the full scope of ```compute.snapshots.*``` which means you will grant both create snapshot and delete snapshot and not only block deletes as the question says.